# How to chain two readers in Spring Batch using Java configuration

Tags: spring-batch, spring-java-config

This is a Spring Batch problem.

I would like to read some information from a CSV, then use that to read from two different tables in a database, then perform an update on those rows.  I have a reader than reads from a CSV, and can write to two tables by making a composite writer.

I would prefer a solution that uses Java configuration (it's too bad so many examples use XML configuration on the Web, and haven't been updated to do Java configuration).

The more sample code that you can provide, the better, in particular, if I had to use a listener or a processor, how would I perform the query and get the result.

Answer (score 0):

What you're really looking for isn't chaining of readers but using an `ItemProcessor` to enrich the data that was read in from the CSV.  I'd expect your step to be something along the lines of `FlatFileItemReader` for the reader, your own custom `ItemProcessor` that enriches the object provided from the reader, and then (as you mentioned) a `CompositeItemWriter` that delegates the writes to the appropriate other writers.